# What is the canonical origin of the Druun, and where can it be found?

Tags: raya-and-the-last-dragon

In Disney's Raya and the Last Dragon, what is the canonical origin of the Druun, and where can it be found (EG, is it in a comic, a movie tie in novel, etc)?

Comment: *"A plague born from human discord. They have always been here, waiting for a moment of weakness to attack. They're, like, the opposite of dragons. Instead of bringing water and life to the world, they're like a relentless fire that consumes everything in its wake, until there's nothing left except ash and stone."*

Comment: OK, but what does that mean? Are they antibodies seeing humanity as a threat, were they created by dark magic, are they the dragon's own inner darkness?

Comment: Dunno. It just says that at the start of the film. I suspect you're giving this more thought than the actual writers did.